# How to change the url dynamically in Dropzone.js via an extra request?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dropzone.js, synchronous

I need each uploaded file to have a different url. If those upload urls were known beforehand, this would be easily done through:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  init: function() {
    this.on("processing", function(file) {
      this.options.url = "/some-other-url";
    });
  }
};
```

However, in my case the each url must be requested from the server, right before submitting the file. What I would like is a way have the processing only start when the result of the ajax request (for the upload url) has returned. Is there a way to have processing wait for the request's callback?

What if I made a synchronous request, as shown below? Are there major disadvantages given the request is a small one?

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  init: function() {
    this.on("processing", function(file) {
      // synchronous request
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("GET", "give-me-upload-url-please", false);
      // synchronous request with false
      xhr.send(null);
      this.options.url = xhr.responseText;
    });
  }
};
```

Thank you.

Comment: Looks ok, if you are only asking for an url, it shouldn't be a problem, otherwise I don't think there is a way to make dropzone wait for that url.